# How to use special char in TextView in android

Tags: android

I am using special char '&' in Text of Android.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please don't include your phone number, email address and or any website URLs, We may filter part or all of your message, in particular if it includes such contact information, as this is contrary to our T&Cs" />
```

But got issue because of &..
How to use this special char.

Comment: Just use **`&amp;`**  i.e ***&(Ampersand)*** in place of **`&`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please mouse over the error and it auto corrects the issue. And yes of course `&amp` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **&(Ampersand)** character in a string literal as `&amp;` which is equal to `&`.

> Your text:

```
android:text="Please don't include your phone number, email address and or any website URLs, We may filter part or all of your message, in particular if it includes such contact information, as this is contrary to our T&amp;Cs"
```